# I hosted Opencart on openshift, But after CNAME mapping, Application is showing 404 Error

Tags: opencart, openshift, cname

I have successfully deployed opencart on openshift, and It is running properly with the url provided by the openshift, But when I have mapped that URL with the CNAME in my domain name, It is showing Error that App is not found.

Can someone please help me for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to set your alias to the domain name you have chosen. You can do this via the web console. Aliases are what allow you to use your own domain names for your applications on OpenShift.

It's a 2 step process

(1) Set up the CNAME record with your DNS provider

> it sounds like you have already done this at your DNS provider

(2) Configure OpenShift to use your alias

> so from the web console, go to your application's main page by clicking on Settings icon then click on "Change" link to enter your custom domain name  e.g. www.example.com or something.example.com.

Let us know if that works,

Diane